# Вывод текста на страницу из виз.редактора WP

Tags: wordpress, редактор

Нужно вывести тест из виз.редактора одной страницы в шаблон архива. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_content

Comment: Не первый раз уже вижу элементарные вопросы по WP от вас. Постарайтесь сначала погуглить их (http://joxi.ru/zANLap5U6nwJnm), или воспользоваться поиском по сайту https://wp-kama.ru/

Comment: Возможно они элементарные для Вас Vantal, но когда не получается реализовать код, зная что ходишь в 3х соснах, задаю такие вопросы.

Comment: Я понимаю что вопрос не из "квантовой физики", но не могу привязать функцию "the_content" к конкретной страницы ( зная ее ID), где находится редактор с текстом. Так что буду очень признателен за помощь. Ладно, буду далее смотреть инет. С постами было бы проще - они имеют свой ID, а у редактора его нет (точнее, я его не знаю).

Answer (score 0):

Хотя вопрос и простой, но занял у меня несколько часов. Надеюсь я кому-то сэкономлю время.
Итак, ответ:

```
<?php $post_id = get_post(30);
$content = $post_id->post_content;
echo $content; ?>
```

*30 - ID страницы с текстом

Или еще лучше, что сохранить стиль текста

```
<?php 
        $post_id = get_post(30);
        $content = $post_id->post_content;
        echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
        ?>
```